# CWinThread worker GetMessage pump gives unexpected MSG.message values

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mfc

In a C++/MFC based Windows desktop application I have some CWinThread workers that I PostThreadMessage to. The threads are created via AfxBeginThread and their message function consists of a queue like this:

```
UINT WorkerThread(LPVOID arg)
{
    // ... init, create pump, flag readyness then pump:
    MSG msg;
    while ( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) ) {
        // Same results with while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
        switch ( msg.message ) {
        case VALID_MSG1: /*do stuff*/ break;
        case VALID_MSG2: /*do stuff*/ break;
        case WM_NULL: 
            // Why do I get this?
            // What is the best way to handle it?
            // Do not try to filter them out in GetMessage, they will fill the queue!
            break;
        default:   /*log unexpected*/ break;
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes I get a storm of messages where msg.message == WM_NULL(0) and it makes me wonder if I'm just doing it wrong.

One thing common between two of the threads where I've seen this most often is their use of WinInet's CInternetSession, CHttpConnection, and CHttpFile. Maybe somewhere they use a CSocket and get additional messages on the thread due to that.

Why would I get msg.message == WM_NULL or any other value that I didn't PostMessage to the handle of this thread?

What should I do with those messages? Is it OK to just drop them like I am? My worker threads have no GUI so it doesn't seem like I should pass them on to DispatchMessage.

If I do as little with them as possible the message storm passes quickly and things are back to normal. If I try to filter them with GetMessage and never process the unfiltered messages the queue will fill up with these WM_NULL messages and the expected messages are rejected.

Should I instead be extending and using CWinThread::PumpMessage? *(Seems like overkill.)*

It makes me think I should just use some standard C++ stuff to implement my threads and work queues despite the use of PostMessage & PostThreadMessage in other parts of the code.

*Updated the post to consolidate the answers to questions posed and insights given.*

Comment: Don't use a `while` loop to pump the queue like that, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx) even tells you not to do that.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx) and the [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx#creating_loop) show a loop, `while (GetMessage(`...

Comment: Go back and read the documentation but this time try to pay attention. It explicitly tells you **not** to do `while ( GetMessage(...) )` because the call to `GetMessage` can return `-1` as an error.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Oh, you mean without checking for -1. I decided to trust Raymond Chen on [when will GetMessage return -1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873) because for my use case the MSG pointer is valid, window handle is null, no starting or ending range filter.

Comment: One of my worker threads uses while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) and still seemingly randomly gets msg.message == 0 storms.

Comment: `WM_NULL` is the 0 message.  It's sometimes sent with a timeout to see if a message pump is alive or hung.  In that case, however, that's usually sent to a top-level window rather than a thread.  So this is odd.  Does your worker thread create any windows?

Comment: After you received a batch of `WM_NULL` messages, does your thread return to normal? In other words, is this just a transient hiccup? At any rate, you can ignore messages you do not expect, or do not know how to handle. There is no equivalent to `SendMessage` for thread messages, so there is no sender expecting a result back. @CaptainObvlious: Can you point us to documentation that recommends against handling messages in a `while`-loop?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy No windows or any kind of GUI call, it stashes work into synchronized data structures or uses PostMessage to signal the work is done. I'll look into the WM_NULL/timeout testing and follow that lead. Thanks.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, it returns to normal and things work out best if I just ignore them and do no work, not even logging. I wasn't sure if there was something like DispatchMessage that I should be doing with unexpected messages to a non-GUI worker thread or I was up in the night in using the message pump dispatch at all. Getting unexpected messages shakes my confidence in it as a good solution.

Comment: Ignoring messages you do not expect is the safe solution. `TranslateMessage` deals with input messages only, so you do not have to call it. `DispatchMessage` delivers messages to the appropriate receiver window. Since this is a non-GUI thread, you don't have to call it either. Skipping over unexpected messages is pretty much the standard implementation for GUIs as well. It allows the system to evolve, without breaking existing code, e.g. when introducing new messages (like `TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING`, introduced in Windows Vista).

Comment: @IInspectable: It is worth mentioning that `DispatchMessage` will also call the callback function in a `WM_TIMER` message, if the timer was created with one.

Comment: @rodrigo: This is only part of the truth. It really is the default window procedure, that calls the callback function (as explained under [timer operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644900.aspx#operations) and documented for [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx)). So `DispatchMessage` will eventually have a default window procedure call the callback. But since there is no window here, this, too, can be ignored.

Comment: @IInspectable: what will happen then if you call `SetTimer` with a `NULL` windows and a callback. Will the callback be called from `DispatchMessage`? I think so, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: @rodrigo: Since it's `DefWindowProc` that calls the callback function, it is implied, that a window is mandatory for this to work. If you pass `NULL` as the window handle, you will have to adjust it at some point prior to calling `DispatchMessage` (see the final example under [creating a timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901.aspx#creating_timer)).

Comment: @IInspectable: I'm pretty sure that it is `DispatchMessage`, not `DefWindowProc`, that calls the `TimerProc` callback, and the docs are a bit misleading. See the [Wine source](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/user32/message.c) as reference.

Comment: @rodrigo: The Wine source code of `DispatchMessage` calls `CallWindowProc` for `WM_TIMER` messages. That requires a non-`NULL` window handle. And it's clearly not `DispatchMessage` that calls the callback function either.

Comment: @IInspectable: No, `CallWindowProc` takes a pointer to the callback function, it is actually just a wrapper to call the callback, but with fault handling and some ANSI-UNICODE stuff. The `HWND` argument is just passed to the callback as-is, and can be `NULL`. Wine is taking advantage of the fact that `TimerProc` and `WindowProc` are binary compatible prototypes, so they use that function instead of calling the

Comment: @rodrigo: I take that back, you are right. I just verified that it is in fact `DispatchMessage` that calls into the callback function (doing pretty much the same that Wine does). Tested on Windows 10 1607, x64.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion and insights. @IInspectable would you like to post an answer? If not I'll work up a proposed answer.

Comment: I still feel that there's one part of the question, that hasn't been answered: Why do you get those messages in the first place. If that detail isn't important to you, and all you care about is how to deal with this situation, you have all the information you need. It's probably best for you to write up an answer, since you have working code you can easily paste (if an answer does need code).

Comment: I would love to know the source of them, it would restore my trust in using the message pump with CWinThread worker threads. I'm afraid the answer is some random 3rd party library the large code base uses or maybe due to the use of WinInet classes (the only common thing I've found). I welcome help finding the source of the unexpected messages. Short of that I'd like to leave a good best practice sample of how to deal with them.